# PHP - Object Oriented Practices and Inheritance

Tags: php

This is the basic class design

```
class CustomModule {

    public __construct() {  }

    //Run me first automaticly  
    public function exec($str) {  } 

}

class Randomizer extends CustomModule {

    public __construct() {  }

    //Call me
    public function exec($str) {  } 

}
```

As I am designing a plugin/module system for extern developers I need the `CustomModule->exec()` to run first, I do not want to leave it up to the devs to have to call  `base->exec($str)`.

I want `CustomModule::exec()` called automaticly before `Randomizer::exec()` is called without having to put code in `Randomizer::exec()`. Is This Possible perhaps with magic function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your object requires some initialization before you can "release* it into the rest of application, then it means that you need a factory for this. This is how you should be solving it, if you require to call some method only once.

If such execution happens each time you call `exec()` method, then instead you should be using some sort of containment (in a form of decorator or just you standard composition of objects).

Basically, you need to restructure your code.

Comment: Yes I know, as per my last post. Was messy and a bit crazy. A sign of needing some sleep. Thankyou

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, i would use this way:
Instead of calling _*construct in exec of Randomizer, you can define a constructor in Randomizer and call parent::*_construct

```
class CustomModule {

//Run me first automaticly  
public function exec($str) {  } 

public __construct($str) {
   $this->exec($str);
}
```

}

```
class Randomizer extends CustomModule {

//Call me
public function exec($str) {  
   parent::__construct($str);
}
```

}

Comment: "Instead of calling _construct in exec of Randomizer.." I didnt code in a  __construct() for the sample. But thanks for the tip. Ill fix my sample. cheers

Answer (score 2):

After a bit more thought I realized this is BAD design. I have to keep the code base simple and scaleable and this would only make a mess in large projects.

As the only program calling the Randomizer::exec() is my inhouse built program I can just call CustomModule::exec() on the previous line and get a boolean  response to see if it should continue to the next line.

Sorry to have to end this Q' short